# Coding conventions for ASPX filenames

Tags: asp.net, coding-style

I have been looking around in Coding guidelines and in the MS coding convention. I can't find what the proper way of naming .aspx files is. Should they start with a capital or not?

So
News.aspx or news.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personal preference: Pascal naming convention, but [use IIS to force urls to the same case](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx) for SEO.

Comment: I use the url rewrite module of IIS to rewrite pages. There are no aspx extentions in our urls and everything is lower-case in the browser and "a" tags. Thanks for the suggestion